# Can I compare MysQL timestamp with datetime columns? is it bad?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

So, I have a table where columns "ABC" is a timestamp and "BCD" is a datetime.

If I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ABC > BCD
```

is it bad? and will it affect performance?

How do they compare in terms of performance?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can compare a `datetime` with a `timestamp`. It's not bad, but be aware of the following:

> Remember that although `DATETIME`, `DATE`, and `TIMESTAMP` values all can be specified using the same set of formats, the types do not all have the same range of values. For example, `TIMESTAMP` values cannot be earlier than `1970 UTC` or later than `'2038-01-19 03:14:07'` UTC.
>
> This means that a date such as `'1968-01-01'`, while legal as a `DATETIME` or `DATE` value, is not valid as a `TIMESTAMP` value and is converted to 0.

From [MySQL Reference Manual :: The DATETIME, DATE, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).

Note how the following test cases all works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (d1 datetime, d2 timestamp);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('1968-01-01 00:00:00', '1980-01-01 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('2040-01-01 00:00:00', '1980-01-01 00:00:00');

SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE d2 < d1;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| d1                  | d2                  |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2040-01-01 00:00:00 | 1980-01-01 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE d2 > d1;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| d1                  | d2                  |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1968-01-01 00:00:00 | 1980-01-01 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE d2 < '2040-01-01 00:00:00';
+---------------------+---------------------+
| d1                  | d2                  |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1968-01-01 00:00:00 | 1980-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2040-01-01 00:00:00 | 1980-01-01 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE d2 > '2040-01-01 00:00:00';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```