# How do I get Timestamp minus 6 weeks in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a field named `timestamp`. This is the last time a member was logged in.
I am looking to include a where clause in a query for something like

```
WHERE timestamp > todays date - 6 weeks
```

How would I do this?
I am trying to only include users that have logged in in the last 6 weeks.

Thanks

Answer (score 85):

I find this syntax more readable than [`date_sub`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub), but either way works.

```
WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 6 WEEK
```

If you want to go by "Today" (midnight) instead "now" (current time), you would use this

```
WHERE timestamp >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 WEEK
```

Comment: Wouldn't that need to be WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 WEEK) ?

Comment: The way my answer is written works well. I know, because I do this regularly. I recommend against adding `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` to the where clause, as it is unusual an unnecessary to do it that way.

Comment: Good to know this works. Just found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886269/can-i-compare-mysql-timestamp-with-datetime-columns-is-it-bad) on the subject.

Comment: Just to clarify, you do need to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP( in the case you are have unix timestamps in your column. Without the function, it will work, but it won't work as expected. If you use a MySQL date/datetime you shouldn't use the unix timestamp function of course.

Answer (score 8):

```
where column>=date_sub(now(), interval 6 week)
```

Answer (score 3):

[This link](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/mysql-tutorials/exploring-mysql-curdate-now-060817-1005/) demonstrates how you might acquire a timestamp of yesterday using the format `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)`, therefore your query would probably be:

```
WHERE timestamp > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -42 DAY)
```

Comment: This isn't working? The field timestamp is a timestamp format. Is this query for timestamps?

Comment: Try using NOW() instead.  I guess I wrongly assumed CURDATE() could be converted to a timestamp type.

Answer (score 3):

**You can use between and `now()`:**

```
select somevalue 
from yourtable
where yourtimestamp between now() - interval 1 day and now()
```

Answer (score 0):

for TIMESTAMP there is a [`TIMESTAMPADD()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampadd-function.php) function

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

this will return the timestemp of 6 weeks ago

or in the case like the question

```sql
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE lastlogin > TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score -1):

Any luck yet.  Have you tried:

```
>= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 WEEK)
```

Comment: -1 This is exactly the same as the answer ajreal already provided 5 months earlier. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5091428/463304