# MySQL: comparing datetime with timestamps

Tags: mysql

I am comparing datetimes with timestamps since MySQL [does support that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886269/can-i-compare-mysql-timestamp-with-datetime-columns-is-it-bad).

Let's say there is a record created at datetime B, and I have two timestamps A and C which A is 2 mins earlier and C is 2 mins later.

MySQL gives: A < B -> 1 (True); B < C -> 0 (False);

How can this be fixed without a explicit conversion?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that MySQL does not convert an integer to timestamp thought it is stated in there [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html).

> If one of the arguments is a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column and the other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp before the comparison is performed.

In practice, MySQL converts the DATETIME column to an integer in the following way:

Say the DATETIME column `A` has value `2021-09-14 15:11:13`; when we do `SELECT A > 1;`, DATETIME is converted to `20210914151113` implicitly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).